# Observing weird kubernetes behavior while deleting using yaml

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, microk8s

When I run kubectl delete deployment.yaml, It is displayed on cli that the deployment is deleted. The pod also gets into terminating state. But a new pod is again created with the same deployment and replica-set.

On further digging in I found out that deployment and RS are not being removed. Any reason why deployment and RS wouldn't be removed? Why would the be terminated if deployment isn't removed?

Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: You may be running `argocd`  or similar thing in your cluster. Consider providing `kubectl  get ns` output.

Comment: Yes I'm running argocd. How is argocd this? I don't have access to cluster rn. WIll send you once I get it. Please suggest a potential fix.

Answer (score 1):

As OP confirmed in the comments that they are running `argocd` then the recreation of the resources is **expected** behaviour **if** argocd is running in auto sync mode for the impacted namespace.

Here is a short snippet from the document

> Argo CD has the ability to automatically sync an application when it detects differences between the desired manifests in Git, and the live state in the cluster. A benefit of automatic sync is that CI/CD pipelines no longer need direct access to the Argo CD API server to perform the deployment. Instead, the pipeline makes a commit and push to the Git repository with the changes to the manifests in the tracking Git repo.

Solution: you can disable autosync and monitor the delta and approve sync manually.  *This is something decided at project level.*  you can read about it [here](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/auto_sync/#automatic-self-healing).